# VB 2010 Admin Rights on SQL Connection

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-server-2008, connection

**Server:** Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

**Connection String:**

```
MyCn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;                   
    AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\tcogensan.mdf; " & _
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;  
    User Instance=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;  
    Trusted_Connection=True"
    MyCn.Open()
```

**Question:** My connection string won't work if I don't run Visual Studio as Administrator. So if I publish the project there would be error on the connection string. I don't know what to add or subtract from the string. Any Help?

**Added Info:** The project is an inventory system(POS sort of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying you connect string:

```
SQLServer = "User-PCName\SQLEXPRESS" ' assumes default instance name was used at install
SQLDatabase = "tcogensan"
ConnectString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True", SQLServer, SQLDatabase)
```

If the login fails then the security permissions on the server/database need attention. Can you get to the data via SQL Server Manager? Or Visual Studio?

Comment: I could get to the data via SQL Server Manager. On Visual Studio I can only open the Database if I Run Visual Studio as administrator. I need to open/edit/modify the data even if the project is Run only as Guest, How do I do that?  <br/> This is my first project so I am still learning.

Comment: `Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'User-PC\User'.`  <br\> This is the error on the connection string If I Dont Run Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: I suggest you do a search: `sql server security tutorial`. I think you just have some basic SQL Server user security configuration problems. Users need permission to login to the server and to access the individual database objects.

Comment: OK..thanks..gonna do that..be back If I found nothing

Comment: Hi, I hope your not anoyed. I`ve done my reading and this is the Tutorial that I`m trying to follow [http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10432.database-security-tutorial].   Just wanna ask about the code that you gave in simplifying the connection string. What is the declaration for **SQLServer**, **SQLDatabase** and **ConnectString**?  Thanks